# Automating PGP Decryption

Tags: gnupg, openpgp

I will be receiving PGP encrypted files from a customer through sFTP - I already have a process to automate pulling of files. Once I receive the encrypted file, I'd like to automate decryption.

I created a key pair with GoAnywhere OpenPGP Studio (public key will go to customer). I want to use the private key along with the secret passphrase in a batch file script that will run as a scheduled task in Windows Task Scheduler. This is my script:

```
gpg --keyring "C:\UserFolder\.openpgpstudio\keys\pubring.pkr" --secret-keyring "C:\UserFolder\.openpgpstudio\keys\secring.skr" --batch --yes --passphrase-fd "secretPassPhrase" -o "D:\FilePath\testPGP.txt" -d "D:\FilePath\testPGP.txt.pgp"
exit
```

When I try to run my script, there are still some manual steps needed to decrypt files - there are a couple issues I faced:

1. When executing the batch file, a command prompt window opens with the same script I have in my batch file. For decryption to occur and output a text file, I have to hit Enter. This is not automatic and would cause the scheduled task to get stuck.
2. Even though I am using the `--passphrase-fd` option, there are times when I am still prompted for the passphrase - this passphrase popup would also cause the scheduled task to get stuck running.

Is there a way to bypass these two manual steps so that my script is fully automated?

Follow up question: Does the `-d` option accept wildcard characters so that I can just decrypt any found file with a .pgp extension, and am I able to use the `-o` option to output a .txt file of the same name as the .pgp file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `--passphrase-fd` option should be used with file descriptor (i.e. number like 3, 4, 5 and so on), not the password string. You should use `--passphrase` option, adding `--pinentry-mode=loopback`. Currently most likely it works since password is asked via popup and cached.
2. `-d` with wildcards doesn't work, however you may use simple script to iterate over all files with pgp extension

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll try that out. Do you know how to solve my first issue with having to press enter every time I run my batch file? Not sure if that has to do with gnupg or general Windows batch script issue.

Comment: Please disregard my last comment, this is now working how I want it. Thanks for your help!